# Serialising a form from a request and putting in in mongo

Tags: mongodb, go

I have tried to put a form from a request (I don't know the structure of the data that I get for the moment) in a mongo database.

Here is my code :

```
fmt.Println(r.Form)
for key, values := range r.Form {   // range over map
    for _, value := range values {    // range over []string
        fmt.Println(key, value)
    }

}
fmt.Println(r.Form)
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
session, err := mgo.Dial("127.0.0.1")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer session.Close()

// Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

c2 := session.DB("finger_bag").C("finger")
data, err := bson.Marshal(decoder)
err2 := c2.Insert(data)
if (err2 != nil){
    Info.Println("error")
    Info.Println(err2)
}
```

If anyone have any idea how to do it.

Comment: What is the problem you're having with the code you have now?

Comment: @adrian it puts nothing in the database {'_id': ObjectId('589c8e19598eb7cc62b4c5e9')}

Comment: Check the error from `bson.Marshal`

Comment: You don't need to marshal to BSON, you should just be inserting the struct itself.

Comment: And your code seems a bit strange - you go over the form fields, then you parse the body as JSON? Which is it? What are you trying to store, form fields or a JSON request body?

Comment: @Adrian i would like to put the r.form in the mongodb database but i don't know what it look like .... I would like to add is without knowing what it looks like

Comment: Then your best bet is to actually insert r.Form directly. Mgo will marshal the map to BSON and insert it.

Comment: @adrian yes putting directly r.Form worked thanks

Comment: Reposted as an answer since it ended up solving your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the contents of r.Form, then store r.Form, rather than trying to unmarshal and remarshal the request body:

```
c2.Insert(r.Form)
```